# How can i access local app storage in flutter app, when app is overwritten from natiive swift app?

Tags: swift, database, flutter, local-storage, core-data-migration

I have created new flutter app, which is clone of native swift ios app. Both app will have same bundle identifier, So once app launch on app store, Flutter app will overwrite native swift ios app. Now, in swift app i have local storage in core data, which i want to access in flutter app, when app will be overwritten from app store.
I have one approach that i will have to access data in swift code, of flutter app & via method channel i can get that data in flutter, but how can i access that local storage (core data), in swift code of flutter?